# How to add borders of different colors on different sides using axlsx on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I am using axlsx gem to generate excel sheets.

I need to add left and right borders of a particular cell in red (FF0000) and the top and bottom borders of that same cell in gray (A6A6A6).

How can I achieve this?

```
:border => {:style => thin, :color => "A6A6A6", :edges => [:bottom, :top], :color => "FF0000", :edges => [:left, :right]}
```

But this prints out only the red borders. The top and bottom borders don't appear in this case!

Comment: I found this in the source code, but haven't managed to get it to work...

https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/stylesheet/border_pr.rb